# EWS SyncFolderItems history

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

How far back in time does the SyncFolderItems store items?
Is there a fixed number of days worth of items that can be synced using the SyncFolderItems operation or is it all the items from the beginning of time?

e.g: I have a mailbox that is 1 year old. If I run a SyncFolderItems operation today, without passing a SyncState cookie, will it sync all the items from the past year? Is there a way I can time-bound the sync(last 10 days' items), without having a SyncState cookie?

Comment: I see that you have posted the same question on MS Technet ;-) Two thoughts: 1) There is a 512 item maximum anyway (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/office/aa563967%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx), is the question then still relevant? 2) From that same article: "SyncFolderItems is similar to the FindItem operation...". FindItem has a 2 year maximum, I suggest you try that in your SyncFolderItems tests.

Comment: Posting at multiple forums helps quicker responses..Ill upvote your answer at both places if it works:)
The 512 is max num of items returned per call, so that dsnt help much. The info on FindItem having a 2year limit is useful though. Can you provide links to documentation for above?

Comment: I do not have documentation, I just found that out one week ago when doing a FindItem over 25 months ;-) You get an error message saying the limit is 24 months. I suggest you just try the same with SyncFolderItems

Answer (score 2):

Andy-

SyncFolderItems will get information about all items "from the beginning of time" - realize that it doesn't actually get the items, you have to do that separately by calling the GetItem operation. Depending on which version of Exchange you're using it will either start with the most recent emails (Exchange 2010 SP2+), or the oldest emails (Exchange 2010 SP1 and earlier). You cannot time-bound the sync, so if you call SyncFolderItems on a 1 yer old mailbox, it will retrieve information about all the items. Check out this topic for more information: [Mailbox synchronization and EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440952%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

-Mimi